# Open or see the content of a .txt with adb shell android

Tags: android, adb

Well, I execute `ls -l` and got this,

```
-rw-rw--w- app_34   app_34         75 2011-08-30 23:38 dados.txt
```

Now how do I view the content of the .txt file? Is possible?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A few different options, but if you just want to dump to the console try:

```
cat dados.txt
```

Comment: I find the remark helpful that you have to use the "full" path, i.e. cat sdcard/Documents/<filename>

Answer (score 2):

The following command will work too:-

```
adb pull {absolute path to directory/file}

cat filename
```

Answer (score 1):

To show it on the phone screen the command is this:

```
am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///data/local/tmp/file.txt -t text/plain
```

Comment: thanks, i change `file:///data/` for `file:///sdcard/DCIM/`